# problems taking data from html form into jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some issues getting my jquery function to take my data from my input html form element.

Here is my javascript:

```
<script>
$(function(){


    $('#estimate').click(function() {

        var postcode_entry = $('#postcode_entry').value;

        $("#shipping_method").html("<div style=\'margin:20px auto;width:100px;text-align:center;\'><img src=\'ext/jquery/bxGallery/spinner.gif\' /></div>").show();

        $.get("checkout_shipping.php", {country: "38", refresh_quotes: "1", postcode: postcode_entry, zone_name: "canada" }, 
                function(data){
                    $("#shipping_method").html(data);
                }
            );



    });
});

</script>
```

html:

```
<input type="text"  name="postcode" id="postcode_entry" />
<button type="button" id="estimate" >Estimate..</button>
```

I am not able to get the postcode_entry data into the function. if I hard code a postal code in then it works properly.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be accessing the value of the **jQuery object** using a property that is available on a **DOM object**.

use `.val()` for a jQuery object and `.value` for a DOM object.

```
$('#postcode_entry').value;
```

Supposed to be

```
$('#postcode_entry').val()  // accessing value of jQuery Object
```

**or**

```
$('#postcode_entry')[0].value;  // accessing value of DOM object
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the jQuery function `val()` instead of the non-existant property `.value`:

```
$('#postcode_entry').val()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var postcode_entry = $('#postcode_entry').val();
```